# how to handle folder wise routing in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Well I created a routes folder in routes folder I place index.js and module wise folder and file

inside index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vie-router';
import UserRoutes from './userRoute';
import TeamRoutes from './teamRoute';

const routes = [
TeamRoutes,
UserRoutes
]

const router = createRouter({
history: createWebHistory(),
routes
}) 

export default router
```

teamRoutes.js

```
import TeamList from '../folder'

const teamRoutes = [
{path: '/teams', component: TeamList}
]

export default teamRoutes;
```

userRoutes.js

```
import UserList from '../folder'

const userRoutes = [
{path: '/users', component: UserList}
]

export default userRoutes;

main.js

import router from './routes/index';

app.use(router);
```

it does says not match found for location with path "/teams"

What is wrong please guide on this how can we set router module wise also best to to keep router alongside.

Thanks

Comment: `const routes = [...TeamRoutes, ...UserRoutes]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import them all into a single routes.js file. You can put each group of routs in its own file, then import those files and merge the routes using the spread operator.

Here is an example:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vie-router';
import UserRoutes from './userRoute';
import TeamRoutes from './teamRoute';

const routes = [
    // here is a "spread operator" and not an ellipsis
    ...TeamRoutes,
    ...UserRoutes
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router
```